# How long before an app review shows up in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I've had a number of users review my app, but I'm not seeing those reviews in iTunes Connect. How long does it usually take for reviews to show up?

Also, the regions dropdown only contains USA. How do I see reviews from other regions?

Comment: So the reviews are showing in the App Store?

Comment: I have two reviews showing in the US App Store. Not seeing the other ones though. I know there should be more, especially in other regions. How do I see those in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found reviews generally show up within 24-48 hours. The drop down will only show countries that you have reviews for. So if only the US is showing then these are the only reviews that iTunes Connect knows about.